# AOP spring using @Before get java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am trying to learn AOP spring. so I have installed AspectJ  plug in and created AspectJ project in  Luna eclipse  and here  is snapshot of  Project Explore:

[Project Explore][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/el0TZ.jpg

and here is my codes:

***AopMain.java***

```
 package org.koushik.javabrains;

import org.koushik.javabrains.service.ShapeService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AopMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    ShapeService shapeService = ctx.getBean("shapeService",ShapeService.class);
    System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getCircleName());
  }

}
```

***LoggingAspect.java***

```
 package org.koushik.javabrains.aspect;
 import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
 import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

 @Aspect
 public class LoggingAspect {
    @Before( "allCircleMethod()")
    public void loggingAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){
    System.out.println(joinPoint.toString());
 }
//@Before("args(name)")
//public void stringArgumentMethods(String name){
//      System.out.println("name: "+name);
//}


@Pointcut("execution(* get*())")
public void allGetters(){}

@Pointcut("within(org.koushik.javabrains.model.Circle)")
public void allCircleMethod(){}
}
```

***Circle.java***

```
  package org.koushik.javabrains.model;

  public class Circle {

    private String circleName;

    public String getCircleName() {
    return circleName;
    }

  public void setCircleName(String circleName) {
    this.circleName = circleName;
  }
}
```

***Triangle.java***

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.model;

public class Triangle {
    private String triangleName;

    public String getTriangleName() {
       return triangleName;
    }

   public void setTriangleName(String triangleName) {
      this.triangleName = triangleName;
   }
}
```

***ShapeServices.java***

```
 package org.koushik.javabrains.service;

import org.koushik.javabrains.model.Circle;
import org.koushik.javabrains.model.Triangle;

public class ShapeService {
    private Circle circle;
    private Triangle triangle;

   public Circle getCircle() {
       return circle;
   }
   public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
     this.circle = circle;
   }
  public Triangle getTriangle() {
      return triangle;
  }
  public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
     this.triangle = triangle;
  }
}
```

***spring.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <bean name="triangle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.model.Triangle">
     <property name="name" value ="Triangle name"></property>
   </bean>

  <bean name="circle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.model.Circle">
      <property name="name" value ="Circle Name"></property>
  </bean>
   <bean name="shapeService"    class="org.koushik.javabrains.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName"/>
   <bean name ="loggingAspect" class ="org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect"/>

 </beans>
```

The code works fine without using in ***LoggingAspect.java***:

```
@Before("args(name)")
    public void stringArgumentMethods(String name){
         System.out.println("name: "+name);
  }
```

but when I add it, I will get the java.lang.stackOverflowError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect.stringArgumentMethods(LoggingAspect.java)
```

can anyone tell me why this happend? how can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

From java docs,

**StackOverFlowError - What:**

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses
>   too deeply.

This means , **memory (stack) is full** and have no space to store further.

**Why:**

In **most** cases this situation is created by **recursive/deep** calling of methods.

In **Your case**, `@Before("args(name)")` - this line tries to find **ALL** methods with the argument "name", **it find itself** which leads to recursive call and the stackoverflow error.Because `stringArgumentMethods(String name)` also having the argument `name`

```
public void stringArgumentMethods(String name){
     System.out.println("name: "+name);
```

}

**How to Solve:**

Either **rewrite your AspectJ expression** - `@Before("args(name)")`

Or

**rename the argument** like `stringArgumentMethods(String name123)`

Comment: Thanks  for your comment, I tried the second option  but still I got the same StackoverFlow error!!

Comment: What about String abc ( completely different name )

Comment: Did you clean and re-build your classes?

Comment: yes, I did. I also tried with this  link code in **AopMain.java**: **shapeService.getCircle().setCircleName("Dummy name")**; instead of  **System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getCircleName());**  but still I am getting same error